# Jquery Verificar Valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um form dinâmico com vários inputs hidden e queria verificar por 
**jquery** se existe algum que tenha um determinado valor no value é possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom dia Thepeter,

O que o codigo que estou a colocar vai fazer é, em todas as inputs hidden buscar o valor das mesmas e comparar com o valor defenido (variavel compare_value). Penso que seja isto que queira.

```
var compare_value = 10; // Exemplo de valor a validar.

$("input:hidden").each(function(){ // Loop todas as inputs hiddens
    if(this.value == compare_value){ // comparar o valor da input e o valor defenido antes
    // Caso a afirmação seja verdadeira do something
    }
});
```

Cumprimentos.

Answer (score 3):

Se o valor é dinamico, ou seja foi mudado em relação ao que está no atributo do HTML, ent~so tens de iterar os inputs e filtrar o que tem o valor que procuras.

Algo assim:

```
var encontrados = $('input:hidden').filter(function(){
    return this.value == valorEsperado;
});
```

e depois podes usar `encontrados.length` se quiseres saber se há algum, ou somente usar o elemento(s) em outras operações, por exemplo:

```
encontrados.show();
```